# xml serialisation best practices

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I have been using the traditional way of serializing content with the following code

```
private void SaveToXml(IdentifiableEntity IE)
{
    try
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(IE.GetType());
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(IE.FilePath);
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, IE);
        textWriter.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("erreur : "+ e);
    }
}

private T LoadFromXml<T>(string path)
{           
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(path);

    T entity = (T)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
    textReader.Close();

    return entity;            
}
```

Though this approach does the trick, i find it a bit annoying that all my properties have to be public, that i need to tag the properties sometimes [XmlAttribute|XmlElement| XmlIgnore] and that it doesn't deal with dictionaries.

My question is : Is there a better way of serializing objects in c#, a way that with less hassle, more modern and easy to use?

Comment: have you tried soap?....and ofcourse theres the binary...

Comment: check this article the section on soap - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11079/NET-XML-and-SOAP-Serialization-Samples-Tips

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# best practice when serializing objects to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475525/c-sharp-best-practice-when-serializing-objects-to-file)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest to use "using" blocks in your code.[(Sample code)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)

If my understanding is OK, you are looking for a fast way to build your model classes that you will use during your deserialize/serialize operations.

Every Xml file is different and I don't know any generic way to serialize / deserialize them. At one moment you have to know if there will be an attribute, or elements or if any element can be null etc.

Assuming that you already have a sample XML file with a few lines which gives you general view of how it will look like

I would suggest to use xsd (miracle tool)

```
xsd yourXMLFileName.xml
xsd yourXMLFileName.xsd \classes
```

This tool will generate you every time model classes for the XML file you want to work it.

Than you serialize and deserialize easily

**To deserialize** (assuming that you'll get a class named XXXX representing root node in your xml)

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XXXX));
XXXX yourVariable;
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\yyyyyy\yyyyyy\YourXmlFile.xml"))
{
   yourVariable= (XXXX) ser.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

**To serialize**

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XXXX));

using(var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\yyyyyy\yyyyyy\YourXmlFile.xml"))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, yourVariable);
}
```